# In Grand Theft Auto V, in what situations will your character leave the engine of a vehicle running when exiting?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v

When playing GTA V, I've noticed that when exiting a vehicle my char will sometimes leave the engine running - I know this because I can still hear its engine/radio sounds, and when re-entering and closing the door I am able to start moving pretty much immediately without having to wait for the engine to start. Are there any certain events when this is automatically done, or can it manually be triggered?

Comment: If I recall well, when you keep a direction button down, he does leave it running but if you let the animation run without pressing anything beside the exit button, he will stop the engine